# How to wrap a c++ class to python so that I can access its members' public methods (the member is an object pointer) using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a c++ class, call it *Example*, which I want to wrap to Python using pybind11. *Example* contains a member which is a *MemberClassInterface* pointer, call it *memberClass*. *memberClass* is assigned an instance of *MemberClass*, which is derived from *MemberClassInterface*. In the python wrapper, I want to be able to access the *memberClass* object's public methods, but dont know how to do so. Below is the structure which I tried to explain here in text.

```
class MemberClass : public MemberClassInterface{
  public:
    MemberClass();
    ~MemberClass();
    someFunc(); //virtual func in interface.
}
someFunc(){
//implementation..
}
```

```
class Example{
  public:
    Example();
    MemberClassInterface * memberClass;
}
Example(){
  this->memberClass = new MemberClass();
}
```

Some wrapping like this is what I want to wrap; this is obv non-functioning, but I havent found how to do it. I also don't possess the best knowledge in c++ (or in python for that matter), so haven't been able to figure it out on my own either.

```
PYBIND_MODULE(pyexample,m){
  py::class_<Example>(m,"Example")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def("memberClass", &Example::memberClass); <--- either something like this, or something like the
                                                     row below. 
    .def("someFunc", &Example::memberClass->someFunc); <-- how to achieve something similar to this?
                                                       It complains about someFunc not being non-static,
                                                       which I can understand...

}
```

I would like to do be able of doing this:

```
>>> import pyexample
>>> a = pyexample.Example()
>>> a.memberClass.someFunc() <--- this is what I want to achieve.
>>> a.someFunc() <---- or possibly this. But this seems to require someFunc to be static.. 
                 or embedding memberClass.someFunc() into another function calling
                 memberClass.someFunc...
```

I do not have any prior experience in wrapping and feel therefore rather lost here.
I dont expext a perfect answer, but if someone have any idea or could guide me towards someone or something talking about this sort of wrapping, I would greatly appreciate it.

---

**Update:**
pschill's answer solved it for me!

Comment: Are you able to change the `Example` class? You could add a new function `callSomeFunc() { memberClass->someFunc(); }` to `Example` and export it as described in https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/classes.html

Comment: Yes I am able to do that. However, I would rather make it work the way I described, by accessing the memberClass. The reason is that if I were to change something in MemberClass, say change name on someFunc() or added another function, it would require me to change callSomeFunc() or add another callSomeFunc2() in *Example* as well, which feels a bit tedious.
Thank you for your input! Always nice to know that I have at least one solution to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by first exporting the `MemberClassInterface`. The following example should work as expected:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(pyexample, m)
{
    pybind11::class_<MemberClassInterface>(m, "MemberClassInterface")
        .def("someFunc", &MemberClassInterface::someFunc);

    pybind11::class_<Example>(m, "Example")
        .def(pybind11::init())
        .def_readonly("memberClass", &Example::memberClass);
}
```

Usage in python:

```
>>> import pyexample
>>> a = pyexample.Example()
>>> a.memberClass.someFunc()
```

In case that you need it, here is a full example that compiled successfully on my machine. I renamed `memberClass` to `member` because I found the variable name confusing. I also changed the raw pointer to a `unique_ptr` because it avoids some ownership problems. To make the `unique_ptr` work, I had to exchange the `.def_readonly` with a `.def_property_readonly` and a lambda function.

```
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MemberClassInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~MemberClassInterface() = default;
    virtual void someFunc() = 0;
};

class MemberClass : public MemberClassInterface
{
public:
    virtual void someFunc() override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from MemberClass" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Example
{
public:
    Example()
        :
        member(std::make_unique<MemberClass>())
    {}

    std::unique_ptr<MemberClassInterface> member;
};


PYBIND11_MODULE(pyexample, m)
{
    pybind11::class_<MemberClassInterface>(m, "MemberClassInterface")
        .def("someFunc", &MemberClassInterface::someFunc);

    pybind11::class_<Example>(m, "Example")
        .def(pybind11::init())
        .def_property_readonly("member", [](Example const& e) { return e.member.get(); });
}
```

Comment: What would you suggest in the case where there is an `Example`constructor that accepts a pointer to `MemberClassInterface` whereby in python you would pass in a `MemberClass` object into the `Example` constructor?. so in c++ `Example(MemberClassInterface* base_ptr)`  and in python `member = MemberClass(); example = Example(member)`

Comment: In that case, you can add the constructor arguments as template arguments to the init function: Replace `pybind11::init()` with `pybind11::init<MemberClassInterface*>()`.